# What's the latest on adding secrets via environment variables to a .net console application

Tags: .net-core

I have a visual studio project inside a visual studio solution.  The project is a console application.  I need to access a secret value and read about creating a secrets.json file.  I have executed the following:

```
dotnet user-secrets init --project <my project name>
dotnet user-secrets set KEY VALUE
```

I can see the secret K/V pair in the  ~/.microsoft/usersecrets/GUID/secrets.json  file.  I'm not sure how to pull that value into the console app.

Any hints or am I approaching this the wrong way?  It's a simple console app but it needs a secret value.

Comment: There's some info [here](https://staffordwilliams.com/blog/2020/07/27/user-secrets-in-dotnet-console-apps/), but it seems like you might need to add a reference to the secrets id attribute when using a console app. `[assembly: UserSecretsIdAttribute("35c1247a-0256-4d98-b811-eb58b6162fd7")]`

Comment: saw it - tried it - and it failed - I have the key to the secret key in my csproj so I don't need to add it through assembly - the async loading of the key not needed and I couldn't get the code shared here to work for me https://github.com/staff0rd/bags/blob/c25230dbaa596396879ab88ad041e659abc45a0d/src/Scraper/Program.cs#L23

Comment: kind of surprised at the complexity of picking up a local secret for development

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using appsettings.json and .gitignore-ing it.

```
{
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "CloudName": "CLOUD_NAME",
    "ApiKey": "API_KEY",
    "ApiSecret": "API_SECRET"
  }
}
```

In code I access with this:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
 var cloudName = configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings:CloudName").Value;
 var apiKey = configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings:ApiKey").Value;
 var apiSecret = configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings:ApiSecret").Value;
            ;
```